# Found the weekly salary from database

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I have the following problem to resolve:

Create a list of weekly salaries from the employees   table   where   the   weekly salary is between 700 and 3000.

The salaries should be formatted to include a  `$` sign  and  should have  two  decimal points like: $9999.99.

• Tables Used: **Employees**

I've tried this command:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(ROUND(salary/12.0, 2), '$999999.99') AS "Weekly Salary"
FROM employees
WHERE TO_NUMBER(Weekly Salary, '9999999') BETWEEN 700 AND 3000;
```

But I get this error message:

```
ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis
```

Can you tell me please, where am I wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Weekly salary? Why dividing it by 12? If that's supposed to represent number of **months** in a year, OK, but - you shouldn't return monthly but weekly salary, and there are 52 **weeks** in a year.

Something like this, perhaps?

```
SQL> select ename,
  2         to_char(salary/52, '$9999d99') as weekly_salary
  3  from employees
  4  where salary/52 between 700 and 3000;

ENAME      WEEKLY_SA
---------- ---------
BLAKE       $2850,00
CLARK       $2450,00
SCOTT       $3000,00
TURNER      $1500,00
ADAMS       $1100,00
JAMES        $950,00
FORD        $3000,00
MILLER      $1300,00

8 rows selected.

SQL>
```

---

As of your code: if you executed it in e.g. SQL*Plus, it would mark error spot with an asterisk:

```
SQL> SELECT TO_CHAR(ROUND(salary/12.0, 2), '$999999.99') AS "Weekly Salary"
  2  FROM employees
  3  WHERE TO_NUMBER(Weekly Salary, '9999999') BETWEEN 700 AND 3000;
WHERE TO_NUMBER(Weekly Salary, '9999999') BETWEEN 700 AND 3000
                       *
ERROR at line 3:
ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis


SQL>
```

It says that `Weekly Salary` can't be used like that; actually, you can't reference it at all in the same query - you'd have to either use a subquery, a CTE or use the whole expression in `WHERE` clause (as I did in my example).

Moreover, if you used double quotes and mixed letter case, you'll have to do it every time you reference that column.

Also, there's a mismatch in format model.

This *works*, though:

```
SQL> WITH temp AS (SELECT salary / 52 AS "Weekly Salary" FROM employees)
  2  SELECT TO_CHAR ("Weekly Salary", '$9999.99') AS "Weekly Salary"
  3    FROM temp
  4   WHERE "Weekly Salary" BETWEEN 700 AND 3000;

Weekly Sa
---------
 $2850.00
 $2450.00
 $3000.00
 $1500.00
 $1100.00
  $950.00
 $3000.00
 $1300.00

8 rows selected.

SQL>
```